# Radiobutton checked property is not the same as the selected when updated through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Upon some action I have to change the radio button selection, I am doing that from the JS side and the selection is changing to the new radiobutton but when inspected the previously selected radiobutton has the property `checked="checked"` and because of that, when I click on the previously selected radiobutton nothing is happening.

Initially `rdThree` will be selected and I click on `rdTwo` and on the next button click I am changing the radiobutton through JS back to `rdThree`. The selection seems to be changing as seen in the UI but when inspected `rdTwo` has the property `checked="checked"`.

Below is what I tried:

```
method12 = function () {   
$("#rdOne").prop("checked", false);    
$("#rdTwo").prop("checked", false);
$("#rdThree").prop("checked", true);
```

}

Expected: The checked property to be the same as the selected radio button.

Actual: The checked property is not changing, as a result when I click back to `rdOne` the postback is not happening.

```
    <asp:RadioButton ID="rdOne" runat="server" GroupName="rad" AutoPostBack="true" ClientIDMode="Static" Text="One" OnCheckedChanged="rdThree_CheckedChanged" /><br />
    <asp:RadioButton ID="rdTwo" runat="server" GroupName="rad" AutoPostBack="true" ClientIDMode="Static" Text="Two" OnCheckedChanged="rdThree_CheckedChanged" /><br />
    <asp:RadioButton ID="rdThree" runat="server" GroupName="rad" AutoPostBack="true" Checked="true" ClientIDMode="Static" Text="Three" OnCheckedChanged="rdThree_CheckedChanged" />
```

Comment: which version of jquery do you use?

Comment: can you also show the html part?

Comment: @EugenAz

<asp:RadioButton ID="rdOne" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" clientidmode="static" onCheckedChanged="method1" />

<asp:RadioButton ID="rdTwo" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" clientidmode="static" onCheckedChanged="method1" />

Comment: check out this response https://stackoverflow.com/a/5145737/2424861. I believe your radio buttons are missing a parameter.

Comment: @EugenAz actually i have GroupName property set to same value. it seems to be toggling and working properly when selected manually but while changing through JS i am facing issue

Comment: I feel like you're potentially confusing the checked attribute with the checked property.  When you perform your logic, do you visually see the radio buttons actually change state as expected?

Comment: In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, **complete**, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: i have updated the question, there are three radiobutton initally rdThree is selected by default, and i select rdTwo andpostback happens and everything works but next i have a button if i click on that button a server side method gets called and next a JS method to reset the radiobutton back to rdThree. 
From  UI itseems it is reseting but when inspected rdTwo has checked="checked", because of which if i click on rdTwo there is no postback. @Taplar